# Image is not getting responsive with AnythingSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

In my web page I have an anythingsider running. Which looks like this

```
<ul id="slider-main">

<li>
    <div class=" right-2 up-3 ">
        <div>
            <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2015/08/10/zrsLx.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="1600" height="1070">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class=" right-2 up-3">
        <div>
            <img src="http://i.picresize.com/images/2015/08/10/zrsLx.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="1600" height="1070">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And My Slider Image looks like this
[image]

But when the screen resolution is low like 1366x768 Image does not act as responsive. Only few part of the image is shown in web. Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

> Note: [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPdxQp?editors=101) to my demo source

Comment: Can you please upload your pictures, and update your links, so I can see them change as I try codes ?

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor This is my codepen link, where you will get all you requested   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPdxQp

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor Pictures are already there in that CodePen LInk. You are not seeing it properly only because the Image is not active responsive

Comment: I've run into this issue before, ended up writing my own slider.

Comment: What do you mean by "the image is not active responsive"? How should the image look like?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro as you can see he image is getting cropped in my slider. top and bottom part of the image is lost. I don't want it to happen. that is what I am looking for

Comment: so you want the image to be fully visible all the time (no cropping so it fits the box)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes Exactly

Comment: If you want that, two things could happen: 1) the image may be stretched and look bad (if you want to occupy the whole width); or 2) the image will not occupy the whole width and leave blank space on one side (or both), and not look good (but that already happens, so I guess you are ok with that).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro . I am Okay with First option (I believe I could add a big size image and overcome the streching).
But I want to avoid second option (leaving white space) . Can you please suggest any option to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution: update the image height to fit the height of the viewport.

```
$(".img-responsive").height($(".anythingWindow").height())
```

Now this still needs some tweaking because as specified in the question comments:

- If the screen width is larger than the picture width, then a blank space will be shown to the right of the image.
- As there is a footer, the bottom part of the image is still hidden by it, so you'll need to adjust the picture height to the view area height - the footer height.

In the end the code would be like this:

```
$(".img-responsive").height($(".anythingWindow").height() - $("footer > div").height())
                    .width("100%");
```

And that code must be called when the page loads and when the page resizes. You can [see it working on this Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJeQVe).